# print a word, number of times specified by the user in angular js

Tags: angularjs

How to print a string provided in an input box, "n" number of times and this number (n) is provided by the user in another input box. (ANGULAR JS)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `n` and `text` (your string).

Then you have to bind `input` HTML tags to `n` & `text`.

```
  <input ng-model="number" type="number"/>
  <input ng-model="text" type="text"/>
```

And repeat your string `n` times in the view.

```
  <ul><li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index">{{text}}</li></ul>
```

`getNumber(n)` function is required because `ng-repeat` directive can only iterate through an array.

```
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
  return new Array(num);   
}
```

Full code: https://plnkr.co/edit/hYt6ICsWImD1PgVd6LYO